# selecting every Nth column in using SQLDF or read.csv.sql

Tags: sql, r, sqldf

I am rather new to using SQL statements, and am having a little trouble using them to select  the desired columns from a large table and pulling them into R.

I want to take a csv file and read selected columns into r, in particular, every 9th and 10th column. In R, something like:

```
read.csv.sql("myfile.csv", sql(select * from file [EVERY 9th and 10th COLUMN])
```

My trawl of the internet suggests that selecting every nth row could be done with an SQL statement using MOD something like this (please correct me if I am wrong):

```
"SELECT *
        FROM   file
        WHERE  (ROWID,0) IN (SELECT ROWID, MOD(ROWNUM,9) OR MOD(ROWNUM,10)"
```

Is there a way to make this work for columns? Thanks in advance.

Comment: which RDBMS are you using? Your title says nth column and you question says nth row - which one is it?

Comment: @PreetSangha With **sqldf** it should be using SQLite as a back end.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, it is column I am interested in. I've edited the original post. Joran is right, it is SQLite

Comment: sqldf uses sqlite by default and also works with h2, mysql and postgresql.

Answer (score 2):

**read.csv** `read.csv` would be adequate for this:

```
# determine number of columns
DF1 <- read.csv(myfile, nrows = 1)
nc <- ncol(DF1)

# create a list nc long where unwanted columns are NULL and wanted are NA
colClasses <- rep(rep(list("NULL", NA), c(8, 2)), length = nc)

# read in
DF <- read.csv(myfile, colClasses = colClasses)
```

**sqldf** To use sqldf replace the last line with these:

```
nms <- names(DF1)
vars <- toString(nms[is.na(colClasses)])
DF <- fn$read.csv.sql(myfile, "select $vars from file")
```

UPDATE: switched to read.csv.sql

UPDATE 2:  correction.

Comment: Thanks so much! The read.csv method works splendidly for small test files, but I'm hesitant to use it on my 251 MB file, read.csv has wreaked havok on my poor 32-bit R with big files before. Would the colClasses modification, are the number of operations significantly cut down?         For the sqldf function, I'm a little unfamiliar with the syntax..how do I specify my the file in fn$sqldf? Does the .csv file have to be preloaded into a database? If I was going to use read.csv.sql to save a step, do you if I could keep the same SQL  syntax? Ie, read.csv.sql(myfile, sql="select $vars from file"

Comment: Have switched to read.csv.sql.  You may need to use other arguments to read.csv.sql as well depending on what the precise format of your file is.  See ?read.csv.sql .  In terms of performance I think you really have to try it on your data to get a feel for it.  Try it with a 1 MB subset of rows, say.

Comment: The read.csv.sql method gives me the following error:"Error in sqliteExecStatement(con, statement, bind.data) : 
  RS-DBI driver: (error in statement: near ".1": syntax error)". Does this look at all familiar? It works fine (without the column removal) when the SQL statement is left off, and the colClasses works on the read.csv method, so it seems to be the syntax of the sql statment that is throwing it off. Any ideas? Thanks again for all your help, very much appreciated.

Comment: None of the other arguments seemed to be relevant, but if it helps at all my data is all either numeric or single characters.

Comment: Using this data `cat("a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l\n1,a,b,4,5,6,7,8,a,10,11,12\n", file = "test.dat"); myfile <- "test.dat"` it all works fine for me so there is nothing fundamentally wrong with the code.  You will need to provide it in minimal reproducible form.

Comment: Okay, awesome, that data worked. It must be something wrong with my data then. I've been trying to save a comma delimited text file as a .dat, in text editors, it seems no eol character is displayed, so when it is converted to .dat it is possible that lines are getting conjoined. Is there an easy way to convert a textfile of the sort [a,b,c,d[invisible_eol_here]1,2,3,4[invisible_eol_here]] into a usable .dat format, such that the eols remain? perhaps replacing eols with "\n"? This may be more appropriate in another topic, either way thanks for all your help.

Comment: See sqldf FAQ 11 - https://code.google.com/p/sqldf/#11._Why_am_I_having_difficulty_reading_a_data_file_using_SQLite

Comment: Ok, revised my code. The problem however seems to be the size of my rows (~400K columns), I keep getting the error " RS-DBI driver: (error in statement: too many columns on file)". Might this simply be due to the power of my computer?

Comment: Regarding this new error, RSQlite had been built with a maximum of 30,000 columns.  You can rebuild it with more but you still might have the problem that the resulting SQL statement is too long.  You could try pre-processing your file with various command-line text tools. Other packages you could try would be ff, bigmemory, LaF, colbycol and data.table.