# Read only n-th column of a text file which has no header with R and sqldf

Tags: sql, r, bigdata, read.table, sqldf

I have a similiar problem like this question:
[selecting every Nth column in using SQLDF or read.csv.sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15373466/selecting-every-nth-column-in-using-sqldf-or-read-csv-sql)

I want to read some columns of large files (table of 150rows, >500,000 columns, space separated, filled with numeric data and only a 32 bit system available). This file has no header, therefore the code in the thread above didn't work and I decided to write a new post.

Do you have an idea to solve this problem?

I thought about something like that, but any results with fread or read.table are also ok:

```
MyConnection <- file("path/file.txt")
df<-sqldf("select column 1 100 1000 235612 from MyConnection",file.format = list(header=F,sep=" "))
```

Comment: Use `keep <- c(1, 100, 1000, 235612); colClasses <- replace(rep("NULL", nc), keep, NA)` in the solutions in the link you mention except with appropriate changes for your data.  Note that sqldf will read all columns into SQLite but will extract only ones in `keep` to R.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `substr` to specify the start and end position of the columns you want to read in if they are fixed width:

```
x <- tempfile()
cat("12345", "67890", "09876", "54321", sep = "\n", file = x)

myfile <- file(x)

sqldf("select substr(V1, 1, 1) var1, substr(V1, 3, 5) var2 from myfile")
#   var1 var2
# 1    1  345
# 2    6  890
# 3    9   76
# 4    5  321
```

See [this blog post](https://sites.google.com/site/timriffepersonal/DemogBlog/newformetrickforworkingwithbigishdatainr) for some more examples. The "select" statement can easily be constructed with `paste` if you know the details about the column starting positions and widths.