# How to read in a specific column from a large fixed-width file in R

Tags: r

Is there any convenient way in R to read a specific column (or multiple columns) from a fixed-width data file? E.g. the file looks like this:

```
10010100100002000000
00010010000001000000
10010000001002000000
```

Say, I would be interested in column 15. At the moment I am reading the whole data with read.fwf and as width a vector of 1's with length of the total number of columns:

```
data <- read.fwf("demo.asc", widths=rep(1,20))
data[,14]
[1] 2 1 2
```

This works well, but doesn't scale to data-sets with 100,000s of columns and rows. Is there any efficient way how to do this?

Comment: Does [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19706927/read-only-n-th-column-of-a-text-file-which-has-no-header-with-r-and-sqldf) or [this discussion](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/is-there-a-way-to-read-a-specific-column-from-a-txt-file-td881689.html) help you?

Comment: Have you checked the use of the `width` argument in the second `?read.fwf` example?

Comment: @Henrik The negative widths-values? Yes, I have seen it, but this would be quite complicated with multiple columns (first ordering, then calculating the skips etc.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a connection and process the file in blocks:

Replicate your data:

```
dat <-"10010100100002000000
00010010000001000000
10010000001002000000"
```

Process in blocks using a connection:

```
# Define a connection
con = textConnection(dat)


# Do the block update
linesPerUpdate <- 2
result <- character()
repeat {
  line <- readLines(con, linesPerUpdate)
  result <- c(result, substr(line, start=14, stop=14))
  if (length(line) < linesPerUpdate) break
}

# Close the connection
close(con)
```

The result:

```
result
[1] "2" "1" "2"
```